# Запись числа в формате Long

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

День добрый. Вопрос такого содержания использую библиотеку apache poi для формирования Excel отчета. Но столкнулся с проблемой.

У меня есть 2 числовых поля, которые хотелось бы поместить в Excel как число. Но они попадают туда как строка. (И вид имеют страшный).

Дело в том что я используют типы данных `float` и `Long`. Tак вот `Long` хотелось бы бес знаков после запятой, а `float` наоборот с 2 знаками. Подскажите как это сделать?

Используемый код привожу ниже.

```
public class ExcelCreate {

private static HSSFCellStyle createStyleForTitle(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    HSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBold(true);
    HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(font);
    return style;
}

public void create(List<ClientUsersDiscountCard> usersList) throws IOException{
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("лист 1");


    int rownum = 0;
    Cell cell;
    Row row;

    HSSFCellStyle style = createStyleForTitle(workbook);

    row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(0,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("№ карты");

    //row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(1,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("% скидки");

    //row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(2,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("Дата выдачи");

    //row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(3,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("Магазин выдачи");

    //row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(4,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("ФИО Клиента");

    //row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(5,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("Телефон");

    //row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(6,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("Сумма покупок");

    //row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
    cell = row.createCell(7,CellType.STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("SMS рассылка");

    for (ClientUsersDiscountCard user: usersList
         ) {
        rownum++;
        row = sheet.createRow(rownum);

        cell = row.createCell(0, CellType.STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getNumber_card());

        cell = row.createCell(1, CellType.NUMERIC);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getProcent_discont());

        cell = row.createCell(2, CellType.STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getDate_create());

        cell = row.createCell(3, CellType.STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getMagazine());

        cell = row.createCell(4, CellType.STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getFio_client());

//////     Вот тут long
        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getTelephone());
////         Тут float
        cell = row.createCell(6, CellType.NUMERIC);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getAll_sum());

        cell = row.createCell(7, CellType.BOOLEAN);
        cell.setCellValue(user.getNumber_card());

    }
    for (int i = 0; i <7; i++){
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
    try {
        File file = new File("C:/demo/employee.xls");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
        workbook.write(outFile);
        System.out.println("Created file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `Long` нужно тоже указывать тип `CellType.NUMERIC`, но ещё можно указывать формат Numeric в style, создайте отдельный style для `float`:

```
CellStyle decimalStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();  
decimalStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));
```

и затем для `long` делайте:

```
cell = row.createCell(5, CellType.NUMERIC);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
cell.setCellValue(user.getTelephone());
```

А для `float`:

```
cell = row.createCell(6, CellType.NUMERIC);
cell.setCellStyle(decimalStyle);
cell.setCellValue(user.getAll_sum());
```

Comment: Для себя я реализовал два вот таких метода.private static CellStyle getStyleFloat(HSSFWorkbook workbook){
        CellStyle decimalStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
decimalStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("0.00"));
        return decimalStyle;
    }
    private static CellStyle getStyleLong(HSSFWorkbook workbook){
        CellStyle decimalStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
decimalStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("0"));
        return decimalStyle;
    }